# Comparing Booleans

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm comparing two boolean here where the match() returns true and compare it using !=(not equal to) to true and it still returns true?

```js
var num = 'a234';
console.log(Boolean(num.match(/[a-z]/i))); // == true

console.log(num.match(/[a-z]/i) != true); // why is it equal to true?
// supposedly the value should not be equal to 'true' because I put not equal to (!=).
```

Comment: The equivalent you're looking for is `!num.match(...)`, not `!= true`. Evaluating a value according to its *truthiness* and comparing it to a literal `true` are two different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where the match() returns true

It doesn't. Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> Return value
>
> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.

When trying to understand this sort of thing, it is usually a good idea to break the results of expressions into variables and log them (instead of doing everything in one step and only looking at the final result).

```js
const num = 'a234';
const result = num.match(/[a-z]/i);
const resultIsNotTrue = result != true;
console.log({ result, resultIsNotTrue });
```

You can look at the [IsLooselyEqual algorithm in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal) to see how an array is compared to a boolean.

Comment: I see thanks. I knew it was skill issue all along hahahahaha, thanks again